ValueError: expected sequence of length 129 at dim 1 (got 46)
I was trying to fine-tune an image-to-text model using the following code:
import json
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import io
from transformers import VisionEncoderDecoderModel, AutoTokenizer, AutoFeatureExtractor, Seq2SeqTrainer, Seq2SeqTrainingArguments, default_data_collator
from datasets import load_dataset, DatasetDict

device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

model = VisionEncoderDecoderModel.from_pretrained("facebook/nougat-base").to(device)
tokenizer = PreTrainedTokenizerFast(tokenizer_file="/kaggle/input/tokenizer-pretrained-nougat-latex/tokenizer.json")
latex_processor = NougatLaTexProcessor(
    size=preprocessor_config["size"],
    resample=preprocessor_config["resample"],
    do_crop_margin=preprocessor_config["do_crop_margin"],
    do_resize=preprocessor_config["do_resize"],
    do_thumbnail=preprocessor_config["do_thumbnail"],
    do_align_long_axis=preprocessor_config["do_align_long_axis"],
    do_pad=preprocessor_config["do_pad"],
    do_rescale=preprocessor_config["do_rescale"],
    rescale_factor=preprocessor_config["rescale_factor"],
    do_normalize=preprocessor_config["do_normalize"],
    image_mean=preprocessor_config["image_mean"],
    image_std=preprocessor_config["image_std"]
)


dataset = load_dataset("OleehyO/latex-formulas", 'cleaned_formulas')

split_dataset = dataset.train_test_split(test_size=0.2)
dataset = DatasetDict({
    'train': split_dataset['train'],
    'validation': split_dataset['test']
})


def preprocess_function(examples):
    images = [image.convert("RGB") if image.mode != "RGB" else image for image in examples["image"]]
    pixel_values = [latex_processor(image, return_tensors="pt").pixel_values.squeeze() for image in images]
    labels = [tokenizer(text, padding="max_length", truncation=True, return_tensors="pt").input_ids.squeeze() for text in examples["latex_formula"]]
    return {"pixel_values": pixel_values, "labels": labels}

processed_dataset = dataset.map(preprocess_function, batched=True)


training_args = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./results",
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    learning_rate=2e-5,
    per_device_train_batch_size=4,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=4,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    save_total_limit=3,
    num_train_epochs=3,
    predict_with_generate=True,
    fp16=True,
)

trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=processed_dataset["train"],
    eval_dataset=processed_dataset["validation"],
    #data_collator=data_collator
)

trainer.train()

I get an error saying:
ValueError: expected sequence of length 129 at dim 1 (got 46)

I include the entire output below:
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[43], line 1
----> 1 trainer.train()

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:1932, in Trainer.train(self, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval, **kwargs)
   1930         hf_hub_utils.enable_progress_bars()
   1931 else:
-> 1932     return inner_training_loop(
   1933         args=args,
   1934         resume_from_checkpoint=resume_from_checkpoint,
   1935         trial=trial,
   1936         ignore_keys_for_eval=ignore_keys_for_eval,
   1937     )

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:2230, in Trainer._inner_training_loop(self, batch_size, args, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval)
   2227     rng_to_sync = True
   2229 step = -1
-> 2230 for step, inputs in enumerate(epoch_iterator):
   2231     total_batched_samples += 1
   2233     if self.args.include_num_input_tokens_seen:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/data_loader.py:454, in DataLoaderShard.__iter__(self)
    452 # We iterate one batch ahead to check when we are at the end
    453 try:
--> 454     current_batch = next(dataloader_iter)
    455 except StopIteration:
    456     yield

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py:630, in _BaseDataLoaderIter.__next__(self)
    627 if self._sampler_iter is None:
    628     # TODO(https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/76750)
    629     self._reset()  # type: ignore[call-arg]
--> 630 data = self._next_data()
    631 self._num_yielded += 1
    632 if self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable and \
    633         self._IterableDataset_len_called is not None and \
    634         self._num_yielded > self._IterableDataset_len_called:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py:674, in _SingleProcessDataLoaderIter._next_data(self)
    672 def _next_data(self):
    673     index = self._next_index()  # may raise StopIteration
--> 674     data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
    675     if self._pin_memory:
    676         data = _utils.pin_memory.pin_memory(data, self._pin_memory_device)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py:54, in _MapDatasetFetcher.fetch(self, possibly_batched_index)
     52 else:
     53     data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]
---> 54 return self.collate_fn(data)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/data/data_collator.py:92, in default_data_collator(features, return_tensors)
     86 # In this function we'll make the assumption that all `features` in the batch
     87 # have the same attributes.
     88 # So we will look at the first element as a proxy for what attributes exist
     89 # on the whole batch.
     91 if return_tensors == "pt":
---> 92     return torch_default_data_collator(features)
     93 elif return_tensors == "tf":
     94     return tf_default_data_collator(features)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/data/data_collator.py:158, in torch_default_data_collator(features)
    156             batch[k] = torch.tensor(np.stack([f[k] for f in features]))
    157         else:
--> 158             batch[k] = torch.tensor([f[k] for f in features])
    160 return batch

ValueError: expected sequence of length 129 at dim 1 (got 46)

I suppose it is an error in the way images are handled. I have tried varying the preprocess function or defining a customised data collator.
How to resolve it?

Many ways to mess up shape. Here are some of mine: 1) Was cropping or masking inputs to such an extent that a squeeze somewhere in a torch method was collapsing dims where it shouldn't, for small inputs. Figured it out from the unexpected dim (would be 46 in your case) having some meaning for my input, just not on that axis. If you haven't yet, try printing shapes/lengths all over your code, try to reconcile them, and pay special attention when 129 and 46 come up. 2) I needed a different version of PIL, an image processing dependency. I doubt that's your problem, but sharing just in case.


Didn't fix all of the spots where a hardcoded constant showed up, corresponding to the number of classes in a pretrained classifier head I wasn't using, which then interacted poorly with my annotations.

